# How to test error_log with message_type of 0

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

How can I test

```
error_log( $message );
```

with the default destination parameter for universal usage?  The test will not always be ran on my dev machine, and I won't know what other developers have set their php.ini file config to.

Is there a way to access the error_log variable from the php.ini file?

Comment: What do you mean *access the error_log variable*?

Comment: I was referring to what functions like ini_set() and ini_get() do to manipulate the php.ini file. I just didn't know they existed prior to asking.

Answer (score 0):

The message will normally go to the apache error log. If the error logs are saved in the default directory (e.g. /var/log/httpd/error_log or /var/log/apache2/error.log) you can just tail the file to check if the message has been logged:

i.e.

> tail /var/log/apache2/error.log

Sometimes you may need sudo access to read the error log.

Comment: This won't work for other dev employees who have altered their default logs however

Comment: Even if they have changed the default log location your message will be logged there. I mean if the test works for your default location, it will also work for theirs default location. But if you want to be sure that for all developers the message will go to the same log file you need to specify an output file in your error_log.

Answer (score 0):

The error_log here is not your code, but a built in library, so you should not be testing this as the tests for the library will do that.  However, if the log is your internal function, then you mock the log for your regular code to test by calling it and testing return values have you moving along.

If you need to test the contents, then the best approach is to create a log for your test in a temporary directory, and hopefully, pass it to your log routines using Dependency Injection. After writing to it, you can then open and read the log to ensure it has only the line you just wrote.

These tests should be isolated to your log class testing though, not the main application, which would still simply mock the log function for its tests.